# application.js "//= require jquery-ui"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, backbone.js

Most likely what I am dealing with is quite basic, and this is why I want to make sure I fully understand how things work and not just guess what is going on behind the scenes ...

I am working on the development of a backbone application (rails is used for the back end), which had already been created by the time I came into the picture. One of the files that I took for granted is the application.js file. The file has a bunch of "require" statements, and while I understand that these statements load different javascript files, I am not sure how everything really works. Could anyone give me a brief overview of what is going on with these statements?

More specifically, recently I was trying to use the jQuery UI spinner function and kept getting the error "this.$(...).spinner is not a function". From reading about this error, it became clear that the spinner function is part of the jQuery UI 1.9 version, and our application must use a prior version. I do not know how to identify which version exactly ... when looking at the page source, the reference is:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I believe there are only two places in the application that might be responsible for loading jQuery UI. The first one is in the application's Gemfile (gem 'jquery-rails') and the second one is in the application.js file (//= require jquery-ui). What should I do to make sure that I load the latest version of jQuery UI?

Thank you for your help,
Alexandra

Comment: Type `jQuery.ui.version` into your browser console to get the jQuery-UI version. Similarly `jQuery().jquery` will give you the jQuery version.

Comment: First you should ask whether or not updating to the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI is the correct thing to do. In doing so, all client-side scripts will need to be re-qualified, so upgrading these core libs, and any plugins, is not something you shouldn't do lightly.

Comment: Thank you, Chad, for your comment!

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot, I agree, after updating jQuery UI to the latest version (1.9.2), I can see some differences. Still, nothing looks outrageous up to this point ...